# I need help understanding Identity in sql

Tags: sql, ms-access

IDENTITY [ (seed , increment) ]
What does seed do? 
I can't seem to find the answer on google.

Comment: Google it Google it goooooooooogle it

Comment: I tried to google it :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The seed param is the value that is used for the very first row loaded into the table.
Think of seed as the starting value, and increment as the amount to go up by.
The default val for seed an increment is (1,1) resulting in identities of 1,2,3,... 
  If you specified (5,1) you would get identities 5,6,7,...

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Identity field must be of int datatype. 
for example 
Id int Identity(1,1) NOT NULL
You can't insert into that field coz it will be automatically incremented by 1 as in above example. You can start and increment it according to yourself.
e.g. Identity(100,1), Identity(100,5)-increment by 5.

Answer (score 2):

Think of it as a value that auto-increments.

It starts at the seed value, and increments by the increment.

So a table with a column, IDENTITY(100, 1),

First row would have the value 100

Second row would have the value 101

Third row would have the value 102

and so on

It's often used as a unique primary key, since each row will get a new value.